# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Degraded

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am deploying a Django application on Elastic Beanstalk and getting 'Degraded' Health message. The gateway also shows 502 error. When I check for causes, I get the following messages: 'Following services are not running: web' and 'Impaired services on all instances.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix?